# How is it possible to keep install4j logs for cancelled installations by default?

Tags: install4j

[The install4j documentation](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/v/10.0/help/doc/installers/errors.html) states that in order to keep the logs in all situations, the command line parameter `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true` has to be passed to the installer.

Since our installer is executed by our customers by clicking on it, this option is not realistic for us and leads to problems in case installer actions fail and customers cancel installations, because we have no log files of the cancelled installations or the errors that may have occurred.

How can we configure in the installer itself or make sure another way that the logs are kept at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Installer->Screens & Actions tab, select the "Installer" node and add

```
-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true
```

to the "VM parameters" property.